# Time Data Format Non Accepting On PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-views

I have a script that goes into my outlook calendar to change a date on a event that is already posted (Django Project). Basically what happens is it does a query on the date you enter and searches for the name of the event. If it exists, it will delete the old event and post new. My current code im posting works on my dev server that is a SQL-Lite backend, my production server is on Heroku with PostgreSQL. It fails on my production. Here is my code.

```
           print('Authenticated W/ O365')        
           # Checkes if event exists in K8 Calendar 
           calendar = schedule.get_calendar(calendar_name ="K-8")
           calendar.name = 'K-8'
           print('Checking if Event Exits in K8 Calendar')
           print("Event Name:", obj.event_name)
           print("Event Start:", obj.start_date)
           print("Event End:", obj.end_date)   
           q = calendar.new_query('start').equals(datetime.strptime(str(obj.start_date) ,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'))  <-- These are the lines that fail
           q.chain('and').on_attribute('end').equals(datetime.strptime(str(obj.end_date) ,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')) <-- These are the lines that fail
           k8 = calendar.get_events(query=q, include_recurring = True)
```

Traceback

```
ValueError at /eventscalendar/event_request_non_approval_view/49
time data '2020-10-31 14:00:18-04:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'
```

Comment: The issue is this `-04:00` and  this `%z`. `%z` is looking for `-0400`, no colon.  My solution to date/datetimes in Python is [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). So `parse('2020-10-31 14:00:18-04:00')  datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 31, 14, 0, 18, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))`

Comment: So I tried your suggestion. Here is updated code.

Comment: No you didn't. I suggested using `dateutil`. You used `datetime`. You didn't import `tzoffset` which created the error.

Comment: Also why are you converting a datetime to a string and then back to a datetime?

Comment: So im using the O365 Plugin off Pypl . It sends the query through the microsoft graph API . I have tried just leaving it as a dateformat, but i get an error on the date is not in the correct format

Comment: So you were correct, i shouldnt be converting it to a string and then back again. So i just changed my query to .equals(obj.start_date) and it works fine. Thank you

Comment: The probable issue behind this is that SQLite does not have date/time types, values are stored as strings. Postgres does have native date(date) and datetime(timestamp) types. Also psycopg2(the driver I assume you are using) does adaption of Postgres date/timestamps types to Python date/datetimes and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `to_timestamp` function to convert your custom format to PostgreSQL, e.g.

```sql
SELECT to_timestamp('2020-11-01 19:16:59:835', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:MS')
```

Details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-formatting.html

Comment: to_timestamp, will this work in a django and python scnario ? That's what my project is based on.